# std::scoped_allocator_adapator code fails to compile with vector of strings

Tags: c++11, allocator

In the hopes of using it for my needs I'm playing with `std::scoped_allocator_adaptor`. This minimal example uses strings and vector, but it fails to compile with on both clang++ and g++.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <scoped_allocator>

struct SomeStruct
{
   template <typename T>
   using Allocator = std::allocator<T>;

   template <typename T>
   using ScopedAllocator = std::scoped_allocator_adaptor<Allocator<T>>;

   using String = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Allocator<char>>;

   template <typename T>
   using Vector = std::vector<T, ScopedAllocator<T>>;

   SomeStruct()
   :  s{allocator},
      v(ScopedAllocator<String>{allocator})
   {
   }

   std::allocator<char> allocator;
   String s;
   Vector<String> v;
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SomeStruct ss;

    std::cout << "faffing with vector\n";
    ss.v.push_back("hello");  // *** This fails to compile.
    std::cout << ss.v[0] << "\n";

return 0;
}
```

In reality `std::allocator` won't be used, it's just a placeholder. This attempt was influenced by http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#scoped-allocator

The compiler error message is lengthy, but boils down to the fact that a suitable constructor cannot be found.

`Ubuntu clang version 3.4-1ubuntu3 (tags/RELEASE_34/final) (based on LLVM 3.4)`

`g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4`

and with C++14 at ideone.com

Comment: Works fine with recent versions of clang: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a8eebaa29cb53b0 Maybe it's the old libstdc++?

Comment: Seems to have been fixed in gcc 5.something, or rather, the version of libstdc++ shipping with gcc 5.

Comment: @dyp right, that's good to know. I've been at it for hours.